# Apache single dynamic virtualhost configuration for local development

Tags: apache, generics, dynamic, configuration, virtualhost

i'm configuring my development environement on my local laptop (ubuntu 12.04), and having some problems to achieve what i want, i'm beginner with apache configuration.

I created a main project directory, and i'd like to set a **single dynamic virtual host** for all my projects, according to my folders hierarchy.

Here is the folders hierarchy i use:

- Main project directory (contain all projects):

  - Customer1

    - Project1

      - public (project root directory )
    - Project2

      - public
    - More projects...
  - Customer2

    - Project1

      - public
  - More customers...

To access a project i use this urls: customer1.project1.dev, customer1.project2.dev, customer2.project1.dev ...
I've read some thrad about virtualhost configuration that talk about using parts of url in rootdirectory parameter, like this: /home/user/mainprojectdirectory/%1/%2/public
So i started trying with this basis:

```
<VirtualHost *.dev>
DocumentRoot    /home/user/mainprojectdirectory/%1/%2/public
ServerName  %1.%2.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

But i can't make it work. Am i on the right way?
What steps should i follow to achieve what i want? Which file should i edit? All advices are welcome! (remember i'm beginner with apache configuration)

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did it!

First of all, we need to enable two mods: mod_vhost_alias and mod_rewrite

```
sudo a2enmod vhost_alias
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

1] Create a new virtualhost in /etc/apache2/sites-available, i named it zzz-dev

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

#All requests ending with .dev will use this virtualhost
ServerName dev
ServerAlias *.dev

# Get server name of header Host:
UseCanonicalName Off

# Interpret the request url to find the right project folder. Ex: For customer1.project1.dev, %1 is the first part (here: customer1), %2 the second part (here: project1), so the folder for this url is /home/victor/takative/projets/customer1/project1/public
VirtualDocumentRoot /home/user/mainprojectdirectory/%1/%2/public

# Fix for missing $SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] while using VirtualDocumentRoot, the setDocumentRoot.php file will be added autmatically to set the variable
php_admin_value auto_prepend_file /home/lib/utils/setDocumentRoot.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit 

<DirectoryMatch "/home/user/mainprojectdirectory/.*">
    IndexOptions +FancyIndexing NameWidth=*
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</DirectoryMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the content of setDocumentroot.php:

```
<?php
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
?>
```

2] Enable the new virtual host:

```
sudo a2ensite zzz-dev
```

3] Reload apache:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

4] Now, to create a project, you simply have to follow the folder hierarchy from above and edit /etc/hosts file with this line:

```
127.0.0.1 customer1.project1.dev
```

Hope it helps. If anyone have suggestion to improve this config, i'm open.
Thanks